# How to align the beginning and = sign of equations of different length

Tags: equations, align

I have been struggling with aligning equations of different length.
By using this align code (so only using & before the = sign)

```
\begin{align}
    a &= a + b \\
    c + d &= e + f + g\\
    h + i + j &= k\\
\end{align}
```

I get this as result:
[image]

The =signs are aligned, but each equation starts on a different place. If I add a & at the start of each equation, the =signs aren't aligned anymore. Ideally I would like all Equations to start at the same place, then add some white space if needed in order to also align all =signs. So I would like it to look it like this:

[image]

How to do this?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain it with `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  & a & &= a + b \\
   & c + d & &= e + f + g\\
   & h + i + j & &= k
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Very nice! What is the `{2}` for?

Comment: With  `alignat`,  you have to indicate the number of alignment columns – here, two, hence three `&`.

Comment: Thank you! Suchs a clean and easy way

Comment: Is there also a way to have the equations alligned like above, but instead of appearing in the center of the page, let them appear on the left?

Comment: Yes: either you want it be the same for all displayed equations, and you have to use the `fleqn` as an option to your document class, or it is only for some specific equations, and you have to nest them in a `fleqn` environment defined by the `nccmath` package (to be loaded before mathtools).